# shell script to find the combination of the array elements

Tags: shell-script, php, bash-script

I have a shell script in which I have defined an array. The array contains more than 2 elements. I need to find the combination of all the elements in my array. Suppose, if my array has the elements, *`{12345, 56789, 98765}`*, I am trying to get the output as,

```
12345, 56789
12345, 98765
56789, 98765
```

I tried the php code from [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm).

```
<?php
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        print join(' ', $perms) . "\n";
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}
pc_permute(split(' ', '12345 56789 98765'));
?>
```

I get the output as,

```
12345 56789 98765
56789 12345 98765
12345 98765 56789
98765 12345 56789
56789 98765 12345
98765 56789 12345
```

Is it possible to get the combination in 2 elements sized output? I am not concerned with the order and so if *`A B`* is got as a combination, I do not need the reverse (*`B A`*).

Comment: You seem to be looking for combinations not permutations if order is not material

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for combinations. I always get confused between those 2 terms :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `printf.` It's the `print function` - that's its job.

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' ${array[@]}
```

You do it like this:

```
( set -- 12345 56789 98765; for i ; do 
    eval set -- $(printf '"$%s" ' `seq 2 $#` 1)
    echo "$*"
done )
```

#### OUTPUT

```
56789 98765 12345
98765 12345 56789
12345 56789 98765
```

I didn't need `eval` - that was dumb. Here's a better one:

```
( set -- 12345 56789 98765 ; 
until [ $((i=i+1)) -gt $# ] ; do
    set -- $(s=$1 ; shift ; printf '%s\n' "$@" "$s")
    printf '%s ' "$@" ; echo
done)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
56789 98765 12345
98765 12345 56789
12345 56789 98765
```

And then if you want only two elements you just change it a little bit - one more line:

```
( set -- 12345 56789 98765 ;
    until [ $((i=i+1)) -ge $# ] ; do
        set -- $(s=$1 ; shift ; printf '%s\n' "$@" "$s")
        v="${v}$(printf '%s ' "$@")"
    done ; printf "%s\t%s\n" $v
    )
```

#### OUTPUT

```
56789   98765
12345   98765
12345   56789
```

I do this all of the time, but never the bashisms. I always work with the real shell array so it took a few minutes to get hold of it.

Here's a little script I wrote for another answer:

```
    abc="a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
for l in $abc ; do { 
        h= c= ; [ $((i=i+1)) -gt 26 ] && n=$((n+26)) i=
    xyz=$(x=${xyz:-$abc} ;\
        printf %s\\n ${x#?} $l)
    mid=$(set -- $xyz ; eval echo \$$((${#}/4))) ;\
        echo "$mid $l" >&2 ;
        [ $(((i+n)%${mod=3})) -eq 0 ] && c="$mid" h="${xyz%"$mid"*}"
    line="$(printf '%s ' $h $c ${xyz#"$h"})"
    printf "%s$(printf %s ${xyz#?}${mid})\n" \
        ${line} >|/tmp/file$((i+n))
} ; done
```

This writes to 26 files. They look like this only they increment per file:

```
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ccdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
dcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ecdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
fcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
gcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
hcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
icdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
jcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
kcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
lcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
mcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ncdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ocdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
pcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
qcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
rcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
scdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
tcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ucdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
vcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
wcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
xcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
ycdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
zcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
acdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzag
```

Comment: I need all the combinations. with printf it is just splitting the input into 2 variables and printing. I tried the array `array+=(s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7)`.

Comment: Ok. So printf printf.

Comment: Nopes. It is not working.

Comment: @Ramesh - it does now, though at first I didn't understand what you were asking. It'll shuffle through all the args you care to give it.

Comment: thanks for the script in shell itself. I will take a look into it as soon as I get into server tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out the way to print the elements in 2 element sized combinations. The php code is as below.

```
<?php
function pc_array_power_set($array) {
    // initialize by adding the empty set
    $results = array(array( ));

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));
    return $results;
}
$set = array('12345', '56789', '98765');
$power_set = pc_array_power_set($set);
foreach (pc_array_power_set($set) as $combination) {
    if (2 == count($combination)) {
        print join("\t", $combination) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

The above code prints the output as,

```
56789   12345
98765   12345
98765   56789
```

Reference for the above code is [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_25.htm#phpckbk-CHP-4-SECT-25).

Comment: if you are going to use `php` you might as well use `python`: `python -c 'from itertools import combinations;from sys import stdin; print list(combinations(stdin.readline().split(), 2))' <<<'12345 56789 98765'`