# awk - to add a column after matching the remaining columns

Tags: awk, perl

I have a file (***file1.txt***) with the contents as below.

```
8145216 3377090 1.5
1405541 53595498 1.53637
```

I need to generate all the possible combinations for the first 2 columns in the above file. I use a `php` program as discussed in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123800/shell-script-to-find-the-combination-of-the-array-elements) answer to generate all the combinations.

After finding out the combinations, I have my file as below.

```
3377090 8145216
1405541 8145216
1405541 3377090
53595498 8145216
53595498 3377090
53595498 1405541
```

In the above file, I need to append the 3rd column values from ***file1.txt*** and if the value is not present in the ***file1.txt*** I need to append 0 as the 3rd column. The final output that am trying to get is,

```
3377090 8145216 1.5
1405541 8145216 0
1405541 3377090 0
53595498 8145216 0
53595498 3377090 0
53595498 1405541 1.53637
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1>=$2?$1SUBSEP$2:$2SUBSEP$1]=$3;next};
{k=$1>=$2?$1SUBSEP$2:$2SUBSEP$1; print $0, k in a?a[k]:0}' file1.txt file2.txt
3377090 8145216 1.5
1405541 8145216 0
1405541 3377090 0
53595498 8145216 0
53595498 3377090 0
53595498 1405541 1.53637
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. I will check this answer also as soon as I get into the server. :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just do the whole thing in Awk from the original file rather than half in PHP and half in Awk or Perl. Given ***file1.txt*** above, the following will produce the desired output:

```awk
{
    Vals[$1]++;
    Vals[$2]++;
    Third_col[$1, $2] = Third_col[$2, $1] = $3;
}
END{
    for (i in Vals) {
        for (j in Vals) { 
            if (i == j || (i SUBSEP j in printed)) { continue } 
            Third_col_val = (i SUBSEP j in Third_col) ? Third_col[i, j] : 0; 
            print i, j, Third_col_val; 
            printed[j, i]++; 
            printed[i, j]++ 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Note that this takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time, so for very large lists (millions of rows), it will become slow and memory intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}
    {print $0,a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]:a[$2,$1]?a[$2,$1]:0}
' file1 file2
3377090 8145216 1.5
1405541 8145216 0
1405541 3377090 0
53595498 8145216 0
53595498 3377090 0
53595498 1405541 1.53637
```